# Settings tool plugin in cordova +ios app development

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I am creating my app with `cordova 2.1.0` framework. I want to add an option in settings page of the device(IPOD/Iphone/Ipad) with a name value pair. So, basically on deployment, the settings tool should get populated with a new option. Is there a cordova plugin to establish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this one is of help ?
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ApplicationPreferences

Also note that you will have to create a Settings Bundle outside Cordova, read up here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html