# iOS App Settings/Preferences in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on a Hybrid Application, targeting (for the moment) iOS.  Does Worklight have a utility to handle application settings/preferences for iOS?  I know how to write the native code to do this, but do not yet know how to gain access to the application settings from the JavaScript.  Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In application-descriptor.xml, there is a worklightSettings flag you can set, **however** the settings page it creates is **not user facing**. That is, it is meant only for development time, or internal usage, and not production. It allows control of the server address that athe client connects to and change the web resources it will fetch.

So the answer is, no.

The mentioned settings page has set items in it that cannot be altered much (settings.bundle which does not allow much room for play. Maybe you could change it a bit, but doing so would void giving support to you if problems arise). I would recommend against doing so.

So this leaves you the option of creating this on your own. Maybe there is an existing Cordova plug-in that does something similar. [Review these training modules of how to incorporate Cordova plug-ins to your application](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova). Cordova bridges between JavaScript to native code, so it could be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  As a followup, do you anticipate this functionality being added to Worklight at some point?  Also, for any others that might find this question helpful, I was able to find the following SO topic with a link to a plugin that might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331113/settings-tool-plugin-in-cordova-ios-app-development

Comment: I don't do product decisions so I do not know. :) That said, you can always submit a feature request: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25